# MongoDB make all key values of a specific field their own field (Python)

Tags: mongodb, database-design, pymongo

My current collection has documents with the following format

```
{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'sport': 'Basketball'
}

{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'sport': 'Soccer'
}


{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'sport': 'Tennis'
}

...

{'name': 'Caroline',
'school': 'UCSD',
'sport': 'Basketball'
}

{'name': 'Caroline',
'school': 'UCSD',
'sport': 'Soccer'
}


{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'sport': 'Volleyball'
}
```

What I want to do is make all of the values of `sport` their own field, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that. I've tried researching ways to "switch" key value pairs, but I can't find a way to in MongoDB with Python (ex: PyMongo)

```
{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'Basketball': 1
}

{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'Soccer':1
}


{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'Tennis':1
}

...

{'name': 'Caroline',
'school': 'UCSD',
'Basketball':1
}

{'name': 'Caroline',
'school': 'UCSD',
'Soccer':1
}


{'name': 'Bob',
'school': 'UCLA',
'Volleyball':1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value pair to object, k is sport and v is 1
- `$mergeObjects` to merge required fields and above converted object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merge objects to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            name: "$name",
            school: "$school"
          },
          {
            $arrayToObject: [[{ k: "$sport", v: 1 }]]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hdASBe8W29T)

Comment: Thank you SO much! I didn't even know $mergeObjects was an aggregation pipeline operator!

Comment: If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask